# PowerShell script to look for particular word in the file and add “4” at the beginning of the line

Tags: linux, powershell, unix, awk, sed

```
I am the best.  Page
I am good.       Page
I am funny.       Page
```

Output:

```
4 I am the best.  Page
4 I am good.       Page
4 I am funny.       Page
```

PowerShell script needs to look for “page”  and add “4” at the beginning of the line. I have created this script:

```
powershell -Command “sed ‘s/^Page/4 &/‘c:\users*.txt >test.txt”
```

but it didn't work in PowerShell.

Comment: Why is your question tagged "linux", "unix", "awk", and "sed" when you're apparently on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\path\to\my\file.txt" 
$newcontent = $null

Foreach($line in $content)
{
    if($line -ne "")
    {
        $line = "4 "+"$line`r`n"
        $newcontent += $line
    }
    else
    {
        $newcontent += "`r`n"
    }
} 

Set-Content -Path "C:\path\to\my\file.txt" -Value $newcontent
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a Unix commandline tool that isn't commonly installed on Windows (although there are [Windows ports](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) of it).

The PowerShell way of doing what you're asking is

```
(Get-Content 'c:\users\*.txt') -replace '.*page','4$&' | Set-Content 'test.txt'
```

or (using aliases and redirection for reduced typing):

```
(cat 'c:\users\*.txt') -replace '.*page','4$&' > 'test.txt'
```

---

If you want to update each file separately (note: that is **NOT** what your Unix code snippet does) you'd do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace '.*page','4$&' | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

or (again using aliases):

```
ls 'c:\users\*.txt' | %{(cat $_.FullName) -replace '.*page','4$&' | sc $_.FullName}
```

Note that you cannot use redirection in this case, because the redirection operator would open the file for writing before `cat` could read it, which would effectively truncate the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -command "foreach($ln in cat 'c:\users*.txt'){if($ln -match 'page'){write-host '4'$ln}}"
```

or

```
powershell -command "foreach($ln in cat 'c:\users*.txt'){if($ln -match 'page'){write-host '4'$ln}else{echo $ln}}"
```

depending on whether you only want to output lines with "page" in them.

Note also that powershell does not have a built in alias for `sed` and your `/^Page/` would have only matched "page" at the beginning of a line in anycase.

Comment: Powershell -command “foreach($ln in cat ‘c:\users*.txt){if($ln -match ‘page’) {write-host ‘4’$ln} | Set-Content $_}”   I used this script but its not updating the txt file.

Comment: I am able to see the changes in output window but the original file is not getting updated with new values.

Comment: You originally were creating a test.txt file. Simply add > test.txt to the end of the command line.

Comment: user folder have multiple .TXT files so  when i run the script it need to update same .TXT files. Dont want to create new file in user folder.

Comment: You could wrap cat $file -replace and sc inside a foreach($file in ls 'c:\users*.txt'){ ... } loop. Note: type powershell -command "alias" to see common alias names like "cat", or better yet, work directly in a PowerShell window instead of a cmd window - at least while you are trying to get your command line right.

Comment: i tried putting sc inside foreach but doesnt work. Can you show me where i need to put sc in this powershell -command